# Water supply tube elimination in the refrigerator icemaker

Tags: ice-maker, ice

Is it possible to eliminate water line, supplying the ice maker in the refrigerator, with a refill system similar to the coffee makers? It would be a lot safer not to use leaking faucets and free moving to any spot in the room, not stuck with the water line.

Comment: Volume for an ice maker is significant, and not as directly user-driven as a coffee maker. Typically you want to have the ice maker several cycles ahead of ice usage, and be able to catch automatically when you use a lot of ice. Plus most people have the refrigerator along a wall and rarely move it.

Comment: If a manually fillable reservoir for an icemaker was considered a viable usage model you would already see this available as a product option. Refrigerators and icemakers have been around for many decades and I have to see or hear of such feature.

Comment: You'd need at least 10-15PSI water for the valves to work properly, which either means your reservoir is pressurized, or is a floor or two above the fridge.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such device. However, when my step-son got married and had no ice maker in his refrigerator he asked us what he could do. I told him that we all used [**ice trays.**](https://www.walmart.ca/en/ip/sterilite-stacking-white-ice-cube-tray/6000187350127) when I was growing up. I was shocked when he asked us, "What's an ice tray?". I only mention this because I am not sure of your age. I am certainly not trying to be funny or offend.

[image: Ice Tray]